# Calling a constructor again throws Typerror: is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have defined a class SchemaProvider:

```
class SchemaProvider  {
  constructor(selectedOperation){
    this.selectedOperation = selectedOperation
  }
}

module.exports = SchemaProvider
```

I am making a new instance of this class in another class:

```
let schemaGenerator = require('./SchemaProvider')

schemaGenerator = new schemaGenerator(selectedOperation)
```

Calling *new schemaGenerator(selectedOperation)* once works fine, but calling it the second time throws *TypeError: schemaGenerator is not a constructor*.
Because of this I am required to restart the program each time for a *new* call.

What needs to be changed in the code?

Comment: You're overwriting `schemaGenerator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're assigning the object that `new schemaGenerator` creates to your local `schemaGenerator` variable, overwriting your reference to the constructor function with a reference to that new object:

```
    schemaGenerator = new schemaGenerator(selectedOperation)
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That new object is not a constructor function. Just use a different variable name for the resulting object.

```
    let obj1 = new schemaGenerator(selectedOperation);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^
    let obj2 = new schemaGenerator(selectedOperation);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Okay. Is it possible to destruct the old object before creating a new one each time?

Comment: @matpadikar - I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Never mind, I followed the other answer(seems to be deleted now). Changing it to 'let myGenerator = new schemaGenerator(selectedOperation) ' did the trick.

Comment: @matpadikar - That's...exactly the answer above (which is why he deleted it), just with `myGenerator` instead of `obj1`. `obj2` above is just to demonstrate that you can still call `schemaGenerator` after having called it the first time.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Got it.